# Changing day translation to different languages

Tags: php

I'm translating a website to different languages. And I'm in trouble, because of this row. I need to translate this day name. Format is %A. It outputs Sunday, Monday etc.

I tried doing this:

```
$day_name = trim(htmlentities($show_day->format("%A"), ENT_COMPAT, $AppUI->user_lang.UTF-8/*$locale_char_set*/));
```

But I'm getting an error. I think I'm doing in wrong way. Maybe someone knows how to fix it?

Here is error:

`Warning: htmlentities(): charset -8' not supported, assuming utf-8 in /home/...../domains/......com/public_html/....../modules/calendar/week_view.php on line 148`

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: that error should give you a clue as to what action is needed, right?

Comment: coppied wrong error :))))) here it is `Warning: htmlentities(): charset -8' not supported, assuming utf-8 in /home/...../domains/......com/public_html/....../modules/calendar/week_view.php on line 148`

Comment: What is `$show_day`? If it is a `DateTime`, the [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method does not support locales and always returns English strings (see the Notes section). [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) does support locales.

Comment: `$date = dPgetCleanParam($_GET, 'date', null);
$this_week = new CDate($date);
$show_day = $this_week.`
So is it possible somehow to fix it with strftime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashes can't be used in field names without quoting them. If the `user_lang.UTF-8` field in `$AppUI` definitely exists then you can access it like this:

```
$AppUI->{'user_lang.UTF-8'}
```

Comment: @TorresAlGrande As Lithis mentions in the comments you'll need to use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)